# Stumped by sticky footer - won't stop where intended

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I'm using this 'version' of sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Here's where I'm trying to get this to work: http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons

I want it to stop at the end of the left column, but for whatever reason, I can't get it to stop before anything other than the header. Is there any way to make it stop after the left bar in the manner that is demonstrated in the first link?

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

#container{
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -40px;
}

#footer, .push{
height:40px;
width: 100%;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #565656, #303030);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#565656), to(#303030));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#565656', endColorstr='#303030');
}
```

If you need me to provide any additional info, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just about to edit my answer because I missed some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want it to go no higher than the left column, but want it to stick to the bottom of the page if the page becomes taller?

If that is the case then the reason the footer is allowed to go higher than the left column is because the left column is absolutely positioned. Because of this your container div has nothing forcing it to be a certain minimum height and so it becomes shorter than the left column when they browser window is smaller.

Try this:

- Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#container` div
- Add `margin: 0 0 50px;` to your `#left_bar` div
- Make sure `#container` has `margin: 0 0 -40px;` (Sorry I told you to remove that before)
- Remove the `position`, `left` and `top` rules from your `#left_bar` div
- Remove the `position` rule from your `#account_links` div

To be honest I'm not sure why you needed to absolute position a lot of this layout.

**Edit:**
I edited the list above because I missed some things.

Comment: I have no clue why that worked, and I'm much too tired to figure it out, but it definitely did. Thanks! If you have a minute, I'm just trying to figure one other thing out: In the beginning, the footer doesn't sit at the bottom when it definitely has enough room to. How can I get it to sit at the bottom there?

Comment: Scratch that. Changes you made fixed that. I was wondering why you removed the margin from the container. Thanks again!